# GeneratePasswordToken throws odd error in MVC 5 (asp.net Identity) - Lost Password

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am creating a LostPassword function using the code below. When users enter their email and they get a password with link containing the token to reset. In my controller I have the GenerateTokenPassword method (under WebSecurity), but it is throwing this error:

Error: Cannot convert type 'string' to 'int'
Line:  var token = WebSecurity.GeneratePasswordResetToken((foundUserName).ToString(), 1440);

When I debug, I get my username in the foundUserName field and it is a string. The 1440 is the timeout on token expiration, and I am supplying an int to begin with. What int is it looking?

Any ideas what this might be?

Thanks,

Sanjeev

```
// POST: Account/LostPassword
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult LostPassword(LostPasswordModel model)
{
    ApplicationUser user;
    using (var db = new MyDbContext())
    {
    var foundUserName = (db.People.Where(p => p.Email == model.Email).FirstOrDefault().UserName);
    user = UserManager.FindByName(foundUserName.ToString());
    //    user = Membership.GetUser(foundUserName);

    //Generate password token that will be used in the email link to authenticate user
    WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("", "System.Data.SqlClient", "AspNetUsers", "Id", "UserName", false);
    var token = WebSecurity.GeneratePasswordResetToken((foundUserName).ToString(), 1440);
    // Generate the html link sent via email
    var code = UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);

    string resetLink = "<a href='"
        + Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new { rt = token }, "http")
        + "'>Reset Password Link</a>";

    //Email stuff
    string emailsubject = "Reset your account password.";
    string emailbody = "Please click this link to reset your account  password: " + resetLink;
    string emailfrom = "mymail@mymail.edu";
    string emailto = model.Email;


    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
    message.To.Add(emailto);
    message.From = new MailAddress(emailfrom);
    message.Subject = emailsubject;
    message.Body = emailbody;
    message.IsBodyHtml = true;
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("mymail", "mypass");
    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    smtp.Port = 587;
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.Send(message);

    return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: `WebSecurity` is not from Identity framework. Did you mean to write `UserManager` instead?

Answer (score 0):

It would *appear* that the compiler is interpreting the `1440` value as a string, you could try declaring an explicit `int` variable for it and passing that instead.

Alternatively, given `tokenExpirationInMinutesFromNow` is an optional parameter which defaults already to `1440` then you can omit it entirely

```
var token = WebSecurity.GeneratePasswordResetToken((foundUserName).ToString());
```

Comment: Yes, I tried removing the 1440 as it is a default anyway, but did not work. I really don't understand what to do here!

Comment: tried declaring the int idea as well, and did not work.

Comment: @Skale Then something is *clearly* wrong, I'd maybe try cleaning the build and even possibly recreating the file. Unless the line you *think* the error is on actually isn't where the issue is.